# $21$ balls in a bag - Probability

Tags: probability

There is $21$ balls in a bag numbered $1$ to $21$.

Two balls are picked at random, without replacement.

- What is the probability of the lowest number on a ball being $17$ or greater?
  Is it simply $\frac{5}{21} \times \frac{4}{20}$? 
  I'm confused because I'm not sure if it matters or not which one we choose first.

Also, if the ball with the number $8$ was chosen, what is the probability of this being the lowest number out of the two balls?

Comment: For your first question, start by making a tree diagram.

Answer (score 2):

@the man The term "lowest" is the key, Think about it (Its a relative term)

It shouldn't matter which order you pick them.

So there are 5 balls that match the criteria 17 or greater.So pick any two of them  $\binom{5}{2}$ over any two of 21 balls $\binom{21}{2}$ which will be 
$\frac {\binom{5}{2}}{\binom{21}{2}}$ which eauals to  $\frac {10}{21*20}$

Second question: If one ball is 8, for the second ball you have a choice from 9 to 21(not from 8, as 8 is already taken)  which is 13. so its gonna be 
$\frac {13}{20}$

Comment: You made a calculation error: bin(5,2)/bin(21,2) is 20/(21*20)

Comment: @user164118 $\binom{5}{2}$  =>  $\frac {5!}{3! * 2!}$ => $\frac {5*4}{ 2}$ = > $\frac {20}{2}$ => 10.

Comment: @BharadwajVemavarapu, your numerator is not double-counting, but your denominator is.  While, for example, picking 17 and then 18 is gives the same outcome as picking 18 and then 17, they are still two distinct events.  See my answer that illustrates this.  Your answer should either appear as 20/(21*20) or 10/(21*10).

Answer (score 2):

User @Browning suggested drawing a tree.  Here's what it would look like with probabilities and outcomes:

```
First = 1-16 (P = 16/21) --> BAD

First = 17 (P = 1/21)
    Second = 1-16 (P = 16/20) --> BAD
    Second = 18,19,20,21 (P = 4/20) --> GOOD

First = 18 (P = 1/21)
    Second = 1-16 (P = 16/20) --> BAD
    Second = 17,19,20,21 (P = 4/20) --> GOOD

First = 19 (P = 1/21)
    Second = 1-16 (P = 16/20) --> BAD
    Second = 17,18,20,21 (P = 4/20) --> GOOD

First = 20 (P = 1/21)
    Second = 1-16 (P = 16/20) --> BAD
    Second = 17,18,19,21 (P = 4/20) --> GOOD

First = 21 (P = 1/21)
    Second = 1-16 (P = 16/20) --> BAD
    Second = 17,18,19,20 (P = 4/20) --> GOOD
```

The probability of the first ball being >= 17 is $(5*\frac{1}{21}) = \frac{5}{21}$.  For each of those five numbers, the probability of the second ball being >= 17 is $\frac{4}{20}$.  Multiplying gives us that the probability is $\frac{5}{21}*\frac{4}{20} = 4.76\%$.  You're correct.

You can use this same method to answer your second question.

---

Edit: Here's a crudely-drawn tree that illustrates this a little better.  I'm adding this because my answer is different than the other two already here and I think that the other two answers are half what they should be.

[image]

Green bubbles are good outcomes.  Red bubbles are bad outcomes.  The numbers next to the arrows indicate the probability of that outcome.  The numbers inside the bubbles represent the possible selection(s).

Following the arrows to all of the green bubbles gives this as the answer:

$(\frac{1}{21}*\frac{4}{20}) + (\frac{1}{21}*\frac{4}{20}) + (\frac{1}{21}*\frac{4}{20}) + (\frac{1}{21}*\frac{4}{20}) + (\frac{1}{21}*\frac{4}{20})$

Simplified:

$\frac{5}{21}*\frac{4}{20}$

Comment: did people conclude this was the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

**First question:**

For the first ball, you have 5 options: 17, 18, 19, 20, 21

However, for your second ball, the number of possibilities depends on the number of the first ball. From the way your question is worded, the order of the balls is not relevant.

Lowest number being 17: $\frac {1*4}{21*20}$

Lowest number being 18: $\frac {1*3}{21*20}$ etc.

Total would be $\frac {4+3+2+1}{21*20} = 2.38 \% $

Alternatively, if the lower number is 17 or more, then there are $\binom{5}{2}$ over a total of 21*20 outcomes, which yields $2.38\%$.

**Second question:**

Even easier. If the lower number is 8, it means that the higher numbered ball is 9 to 21. 13 outcomes out of 20 (not counting the 8)
$\frac {13}{20} = 65 \%$

Comment: @Wasshim H I understand your answer but I don't understand why my answer wouldn't work, but it's double your answer?

Comment: @theman  You selected the balls in order.  However, if you choose $17$ then $19$, you will get the same result as if you choose $19$ then $17$.  Thus, you counted each favorable result twice.

Comment: I don't think this is right.  Like you say, you have five options for the first ball.  If your first ball is one of those five options, you then have four options for the second ball.  If your first is 17, your second must be one of {18,19,20,21}.  If your first is 21, your second must be one of {17,18,19,20}.  Wouldn't this mean that your numerator should be (5*4) and not (5*2)?

Comment: @user2023861  You are making ordered selections, but the order does not matter.  However, as I said above, drawing $17$ then $19$ has the same effect as drawing $19$ then $17$.  You are counting each favorable result twice.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, Why then is the denominator 21*20?  Does that not count every possibility twice?  There is a 1/21 change that I select #3 first and then a 1/20 chance that I select #4 second.  The probabilities are the same if I select #4 first and then #3.  If we're removing double-counts from results that pass, shouldn't we also remove double counts from results that fail?

Comment: @user2023861  You are correct.  I had not noticed that Wassim H had made an ordered selection in the denominator but not in the numerator.